# navigator.geolocation not working in google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using navigator for getting current location on google map on page load but when I am running my code at Firefox its returning the latitude and longitude of current location and working fine, Same code is not working with Google Chrome browser.

I have research and found that getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins.
**Note:**
See this link: [Geolocation API removed from unsecured origins in Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function for showing current postion on the map
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        if (navigator.geolocation) { alert('fn called');
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }); 
    function showPosition(position) { 
        var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log('navigation called');console.log(latitude);console.log(longitude);
    }

</script>
```

Has anyone face it before, I don't want to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to serve the page from https:// for geolocation to work on the latest version of Chrome.

See this related link: [Geolocation API removed from unsecured origins in Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

From the above link:

> Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the user’s location](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/obtain-location?hl=en) using the [HTML5 Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) from pages delivered by non-secure connections. This means that the page that’s making the Geolocation API call must be served from a [secure context](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/) such as [HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/).

Comment: I have already mention this in my question:  I have research and found that getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: No.  You have to use a secure origin if you want to use HTML5 geolocation in Chrome version 50 or later.

Comment: Is there any solution without HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Is geolocation api removed from mobile versions chrome? As I checked out on my Iphone 5 with ios 9, chrome 50.0.2661.95 versions and still got geolocation requests from web pages with http

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late, but may be useful. I used a VPN Proxy software like **Ultrasurf** and it worked. It's a problem of Google Authorization.